# Looking for parents of Charlotte Wood from Middlesex, London?

Tags: england, london, middlesex

Charlotte Wood sailed on the ship Warwick, 1874, arriving January 1875, in Auckland New Zealand. She was listed as Charlotte Wood, aged 18 from Middlesex on the passenger list. I have all documents of her time in Gisborne, New Zealand, sadly she died aged 22  after giving birth to my Great Grandmother, and there is no mention of her Parent's anywhere. Any suggestions to help with my search would be really appreciated.

Charlotte Wood married Henry Tarr, their first born was Arthur Henry Tarr. Their daughter was named Regatha May, which wasn't recorded on the birth registration. Charlotte died of child birth related fever, I wondered if she may have been talking of the Regatta Day in Auckland, which the ship Warwick was involved in when she first arrived in Auckland. She possibly had a broad accent. The baby was adopted by her Father's Sister, and when she was registered at school, was named Charlotte Agatha May Tarr.

Comment: What did Charlotte name her daughter (assuming she only had one child)?  It may give a hint as to what her mother's name may have been.

Comment: Charlotte Wood married Henry Tarr, their first born was Arthur Henry Tarr. Their daughter was named Regatha May, which wasn't recorded on the birth registration. Charlotte died of child birth related fever, I wondered if she may have been talking of the Regatta Day in Auckland, which the ship Warwick was involved in when she first arrived in Auckland. She possibly had a broad accent. The baby was adopted by her Father's Sister, and when she was registered at school, was named Charlotte Agatha May Tarr. :-)

Comment: Have you made a list of candidate Charlotte Woods aged about 15 and living in Middlesex for the 1871 census and looked for whether they can also be found in the 1881 or in a Middlesex marriage?  Do you know the names of anyone who appears to be travelling with Charlotte on the Warwick in 1874?

Answer (score 1):

She cannot be the Charlotte Wood living at London, St Matthew Bethnal Green, Middlesex, England with parents Thomas and Matilda, brother Alfred and sister Emma for the 1871 Census:

> "England and Wales Census, 1871", database with images, FamilySearch
>   (https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:VRJJ-4S6 : 14 November 2017),
>   Charlotte Wood in entry for Thomas Wood, 1871.

because that Charlotte Wood is still living at Bethnal Green, London,Middlesex, England with parents Thomas and Matilda, and sister Emma for the 1881 Census:

> "England and Wales Census, 1881," database with images, FamilySearch
>   (https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:Q27S-8M9R : 19 October 2017),
>   Charlotte Wood in household of Thomas Wood, Bethnal Green,
>   London,Middlesex, England; from "1881 England, Scotland and Wales
>   census," database and images, findmypast (http://www.findmypast.com :
>   n.d.); citing p. 20, Piece/Folio 411/51, The National Archives, Kew,
>   Surrey; FHL microfilm 101,774,258.